# ACME - Acquire certificate for subdomains with SAN

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm interested in the upcoming [Automated Certificate Management Environment (ACME)](https://letsencrypt.github.io/acme-spec/). I download the demos & tried it out with my main domain.
I still have a question though:
Using the regular certification process, I'm able to get a certificate with SAN so I can set it on my server (Node.js) and serve it for all the subdomains (which are vhosts). The problem, is that the [current draft](https://letsencrypt.github.io/acme-spec/#key-authorization) states the following:

> Key Authorization
>   This process may be repeated to associate multiple identifiers to a key pair (e.g., to request certificates with multiple identifiers)

**Does this mean that I need to issue a new certificate generated from the same key for each individual subdomain even if they are part of the same main domain ("main identifier") ?**

Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of this

> to request certificates with multiple identifiers

is that you will be able to associate multiple domains to one certificate. These domains will most likely be stated in subject alternative name extension of the certificate.

Each domain will be validated by CA and only validated domains will be placed in the issued certificate.

It is not written clearly in the specification but it does make sense to me after reading section 5.6, specifically

> The CSR encodes the client’s requests with regard to the content of
>   the certificate to be issued. The CSR MUST contain at least one
>   extensionRequest attribute [RFC2985] requesting a subjectAltName
>   extension, containing the requested identifiers.
>
> The values provided in the CSR are only a request, and are not
>   guaranteed. The server or CA may alter any fields in the certificate
>   before issuance. For example, the CA may remove identifiers that are
>   not authorized for the key indicated in the “authorization” field.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that since it allows CSR with SAN, it will work. Thank you.